# Restricted Boltzmann Machine: How to predict class labels?

Tags: scikit-learn

So I was reading through the [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_rbm_logistic_classification.html) for Restricted Boltzmann Machines on the SKLearn site, and after getting that example to work, I wanted to play around more with BernoulliRBM to get a better feel for how RBMs work. I tried doing some simple class prediction:

```
# Adapted from sample digits recognition client on Scikit-Learn site.

import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import BernoulliRBM
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.lda import LDA

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2,     random_state=10)

# Models we will use
rbm = BernoulliRBM(random_state=0, verbose=True)
logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
classifier = Pipeline(steps=[('rbm', rbm), ('logistic', logistic)])
lda = LDA(n_components=3)

#########################################################################

# Training RBM-Logistic Pipeline
logistic.fit(X_train, Y_train)
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)

#########################################################################

# Get predictions
print "The RBM model:"
print "Predict: ", classifier.predict(X_test)
print "Real:    ", Y_test

print

print "Linear Discriminant Analysis: "
lda.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print "Predict: ", lda.predict(X_test)
print "Real:    ", Y_test
```

This is the output:

```
Iteration 0, pseudo-likelihood = 0.00, time = 0.02s
Iteration 1, pseudo-likelihood = 0.00, time = 0.02s
Iteration 2, pseudo-likelihood = 0.00, time = 0.02s
Iteration 3, pseudo-likelihood = 0.00, time = 0.02s
Iteration 4, pseudo-likelihood = 0.00, time = 0.02s
Iteration 5, pseudo-likelihood = 0.00, time = 0.02s
Iteration 6, pseudo-likelihood = 0.00, time = 0.02s
Iteration 7, pseudo-likelihood = 0.00, time = 0.01s
Iteration 8, pseudo-likelihood = 0.00, time = 0.01s
Iteration 9, pseudo-likelihood = 0.00, time = 0.02s
The RBM model:
Predict:  [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
Real:     [1 2 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 1 0 1 1 1 2]

Linear Discriminant Analysis:
Predict:  [2 2 0 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 1 0 1 1 2 2]
Real:     [1 2 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 1 0 1 1 1 2]
```

Why does the RBM predict "2" for every label in the test data, even though it's clearly not correct (as demonstrated by LDA)? How would it be possible to get the Pipeline(rbm, logistic) to predict class labels? If you could explain this to a neural networks newbie, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: With a Bernoulli RBM, you should be using binary features. Try `sklearn.preprocessing.Binarizer`.

Comment: @covariance, can you post the changes you've done that made it work?